# Unit testing Zend_Json_Server

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework, json-rpc

Is there a possibility to unittest a Zend_Json_Rpc server?
Or should I much rather unit test the underlying class that the Json server wraps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are **unit**-testing, you should not be testing a combinaison of classes -- but only **one** class : the one that does the work -- which is your class.

`Zend_Json_Rpc` is part of a framework ; as such, you are not the one who should unit-test it : it's already tested by the Framework's test suite.

Answer (score 0):

Are you serious? That's not an answer! He means an implementation of Zend_Json_Server and I don't see how that's so terribly difficult to figure out. So either you are feigning obtuseness to make yourself feel important or you really are that obtuse but amazingly still feigning superiority while extolling advice.

to the OP, let me know if you haven't gotten an answer. I have an idea how to do it but was doing a google search to see if there's a recommended way which brought me to this post.